# lodash map get index key got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js, lodash

```
import { map } from 'lodash';

render(){
   return(
      {map(new_applicants, (obj,index) => 
         <div key={index}>{index}</div>
      )}
   )
}
```

What's wrong with this code? obj is the single array of object been iterate and index is the key. I'm using lodash. The error look like this in console.

```
{map(new_applicants, (obj,index) => 
     |               ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `{...}` syntax is being taken for an object initializer; you're doing this *outside* of JSX. That syntax is only valid *within* a JSX section, e.g.

```
<div>{map(...)}</div>
```

Also, `render` has to return a component (or `null`), it can't return an array. So perhaps:

```
return(
  <div>
  {map(new_applicants, (obj,index) =>
    <div key={index}>{index}</div>
  )}
  </div>
)
```

Example:

```js
const map = _.map;

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const new_applicants = [1, 2, 3];
    return(
      <div>
      {map(new_applicants, (obj,index) =>
        <div key={index}>{index}</div>
      )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this, `{}` it required when you are running the `js code` inside `html` element:

```
render(){
   return( 
      <div>
        {
            map(new_applicants, (obj,index) => 
              <div key={index}>{index}</div>
            )
        }
      </div>
   )
}
```